# Why does the below date comparison in Excel return false?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, date-comparison

The two columns in Excel contain custom date in a format of `d-mmm`. The date 19-Jul in column D11 is for the month 2021. The date 3-Jan in column H8 is for the month 2022. I am using the below formula to compare the two dates, and the result should be true, but somehow this formula returns false.

```
=IF(H$8>=$D11),"True","False")
```

Comment: Then the dates are clearly not what you think they are.

Comment: Change the format to General... what is in those cells?

Comment: Also, probably better to return a boolean, not a string-that-looks-like-a-boolean. `=H$8>=$D11`.

Comment: Is your first closing parentheses a typo? It's not supposed to be here.

Comment: And the true and false as the results of the if() don’t need to be text. So =if(h$8>=$d11,True,False)

Comment: Probably your dates are actually texts that look like dates, not dates formatted by Excel.

Comment: @SolarMike - even better, no `IF`: `=H$8>=$D11` returns `TRUE` or `FALSE`.

Comment: @BigBen I agree, but returning true as text as what the OP shows is not the same...

Answer (score 0):

One way to prove to yourself that the problem is likely the format of the "dates" themselves is to flip the formula: If `=IF($D11>H$8,"True","False")` (omitted first parenthesis as that seems to be an input error) also returns "False", then you are not comparing dates.

You can fix this issue a million different ways depending on what the cell is actually being stored as; I'm sure you will be able to quickly find something.

Comment: Why have you reversed the logic? The OP was testing to see if H8   was greater than or equal to D11...

Comment: @Solar Mike because if H8 wasn't greater than or equal to D11 his original formula would be correct (in the colloquial sense) in returning "False". But if D11 is both greater than H8 (as indicated by the original formula) and less than H8 (as indicated in the reversed logic, if it also returned "False") we have reached a contradiction and the issue is how the data is stored

Comment: So this is not an answer, merely a test so should be a comment.

Comment: @Solar Mike No, the question is *why* it returns "False" (not how to fix it). My answer is that, depending on the output of test I suggested, ComplexData is not actually comparing what they think are dates.